# What is "field_s2i" in audit?

Tags: c

https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/master/lib/lookup_table.c#L87
I can't use [grep(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/grep/grep.1.en.html) find out the where it defined or declared.

```
audit-2.8.5$ grep -nr field_s2i
lib/lookup_table.c:95:  if (field_s2i(field, &res) != 0)
audit-2.8.5$ grep -r field_s2i /usr/include
audit-2.8.5$
```

Comment: `s2i` means "string to identifier", so `field_s2i()` translates a field name to an integer id. Conversely, the `i2s` functions translate an identifier into a (human-readable) string

Answer (score 1):

The very definition is generated by an outside program when you run `make`.

I cloned the project and executed make and the generated definition is like that:

```
/* This is a generated file, see Makefile.am for its inputs. */
static const char field_strings[] = "a0\0a1\0a2\0a3\0arch\0auid\0devmajor\0devminor\0dir\0egid\0"
    "euid\0exe\0exit\0field_compare\0filetype\0fsgid\0fstype\0fsuid\0gid\0inode\0"
    "key\0loginuid\0msgtype\0obj_gid\0obj_lev_high\0obj_lev_low\0obj_role\0obj_type\0obj_uid\0obj_user\0"
    "path\0perm\0pers\0pid\0ppid\0saddr_fam\0sessionid\0sgid\0subj_clr\0subj_role\0"
    "subj_sen\0subj_type\0subj_user\0success\0suid\0uid";
static const unsigned field_s2i_s[] = {
    0,3,6,9,12,17,22,31,40,44,
    49,54,58,63,77,86,92,99,105,109,
    115,119,128,136,144,157,169,178,187,195,
    204,209,214,219,223,228,238,248,253,262,
    272,281,291,301,309,314,
};
static const int field_s2i_i[] = {
    200,201,202,203,11,9,100,101,107,6,
    2,112,103,111,108,8,26,4,5,102,
    210,9,12,110,23,22,20,21,109,19,
    105,106,10,0,18,113,25,7,17,14,
    16,15,13,104,3,1,
};
static int field_s2i(const char *s, int *value) {
    size_t len, i;
     if (s == NULL || value == NULL)
        return 0;
    len = strlen(s);
    { char copy[len + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = s[i];
        copy[i] = GT_ISUPPER(c) ? c - 'A' + 'a' : c;
    }
    copy[i] = 0;
    return s2i__(field_strings, field_s2i_s, field_s2i_i, 46, copy, value);
    }
}
static const int field_i2s_i[] = {
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
    10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,
    20,21,22,23,25,26,100,101,102,103,
    104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,
    200,201,202,203,210,
};
static const unsigned field_i2s_s[] = {
    219,314,49,309,99,105,44,248,86,17,
    214,12,128,291,262,281,272,253,223,195,
    169,178,157,144,238,92,22,31,109,58,
    301,204,209,40,77,187,136,63,54,228,
    0,3,6,9,115,
};
static const char *field_i2s(int v) {
    return i2s_bsearch__(field_strings, field_i2s_i, field_i2s_s, 45, v);
}
```